# Android ProgressBar NPE Within Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-view

I want to display a *Progressbar* in my **LoginFragment** for testing purposes however after I connect my view variables in the *OnCreateView* Callback in my LoginFragment, my app shuts down and its due to:

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference`

But what's driving me nuts is that this is the only View that throws a NPE, all my other views I am able to manipulate and reference without a problem. I also tried to use a *Progressbar* in the ***LoginActivity*** that hosts the **LoginFragment** and the *Progressbar* worked as expected, but why not in the fragment ??

I attached the code xml and fragment code corresponding to the **LoginFragment**

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private AutoCompleteTextView name;
    private EditText password;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    //......... Skipped For Brevity .........

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup   container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);

    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.album_jazz_blues);

    name = v.findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = v.findViewById(R.id.password);

    progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   <-------- THROWS NPE

    return v;
  }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_parent_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:ignore="Autofill" />

  </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<ProgressBar
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar">

</ProgressBar>
```

What Am I missing here ?

Comment: Do you have more than one of the same layout for different screen sizes?

Comment: I'd switch tha code from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated`. I've had some strange experiences with handling views in the `onCreateView` method.

Comment: @Aaron I actually did have two different layout folders a normal folder and v-26 folder which did not necessarily mirror each other in terms of elements and attributes, thanks for pointing that out. The reason I generate a v-26 layout folder was due to EditText missing the autofill attribute, and when I assigned a value to it, another hint popped up suggesting I **override resource in layout v-26** since API 19 was my Min SDK

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron in the comments pointed out, I had two different layout folders a normal folder and v-26 folder which did not necessarily mirror each other so what I did was assign the folders the exact same elements and attributes with their corresponding values with the exception of

```
EditTextandroid:importantForAutofill
```

autofill attribute, in v-26 `android:importantForAutofill="no` and in my regular layout folder `tools:ignore="Autofill"`